# Setting iPad Pro launch image without supporting iPad Pro

Tags: ipad, launch-screen

I have an old app, designed without auto layout, that works on iPad and appears to run fine also in iPad Pro because all view controller layouts are getting automatically scaled up. The only issue is that iPad Pro uses the app icon as launch screen which looks bad. This is of course because I have not provided a dedicated launch image for the device.

But if I add the launch image through assets catalog or by using a storyboard then the app assumes that iPad Pro is supported and stops upscaling the view controllers. Now, it would be a huge task to modify all view controllers for iPad Pro and that work also seems futile since the automatic upscaling already works just fine.

So, is there any way to make iPad Pro not use the app icon as launch image and yet let it run the regular iPad layout upscaled? I'm trying to update the app for iOS 10 in Xcode 8.2.